# Strings as an ArrayList and use in another class

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'd like to get my values in an array. Later I'd like to use the array in another class. How can this be done?

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
                    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                    int column = target.getSelectedColumn();

                    row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    String val1 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                    String val2 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
                    String val3 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
                    String val4 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3);
                    String val5 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4);

                    System.out.println(val1 + " " + val2 + " " + val3 + " " + val4 + " " + val5);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, have you learned how to use arrays and loops?

Comment: You could try looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). As for using in another class, you can simply pass the array reference to that class. Try looking [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm learning right now. I used an array in another context. But in this case I'm not sure what I should do. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a new array with the size of the values you are going to add. If you do not know the size you should look into using [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
String[] arr = new String[5];
```

Add values to the array. You could probably put this in a loop so the code will be less verbose.

```
String val1 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
arr[0] = val1;

String val2 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
arr[1] = val2;

...
```

then return the array

```
return arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with collections, they normally easier to work with:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add((String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0))
..
..
values.add((String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4););
```